# Is there a universal measure word in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for the following word. A term that covers the following examples.

> One ____of tea.
>   Two ____ of water.
>   Some ____ of cake.
>   A ____ of chicken.
>   A ____ of strings.
>   A ____ of objects.

Is there such word XXX that exist in English?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I'm not just looking measure words that only fit foods :) I'm look for like a really universal measure word that can be use with any type of subject.

Comment: Can you explain "why" you need a single word? Is it idle curiosity or is there a need?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because I need it to design programming functions API, if there is a single universal word, the API of every function would be more consistent, and consistency  is a good thing in UX design.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just for your information, there is a universal measure word in Chinese, which is 個. 　I tried to google translate 個, however I just got the term "universal measure word". That's why I came to this StackExchange.

Comment: Avoid asking for help naming something. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. Such questions may be closed because they only help the person asking. Sometimes such a request can be salvaged by rewriting to help future visitors. Or, you can look for other naming resources: “[Help naming something – Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=help+naming+something)”.

Comment: Avoid word/phrase requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 5):

The very fact that one translation of 個 is something as vague as "universal measure word" indicates that **English does not have a universal measure word.**

That said, you might be able to use *measure,* or *quantity.* Those are fairly general, but are usually used when comparing amounts (there's another word): six measures of vodka and one measure of vermouth, for example, or thirty measures of wheat and seven measures of water.

Measuring words in English are usually specific to what is being measured.

That said, *portion* can mean simply "a part of", and it's perfectly reasonable to speak of a portion of the Oort cloud, even if you don't expect to eat it. But that doesn't fit your "two X of water", and we wouldn't usually think of water as being measured like that. You either have some ("a quantity of water") or you don't.

Comment: Ooh, "quantity". Yes. Upvoting.

Comment: I can't help but chuckle at the fact that a *universal measure word* is actually **measure**. And that the answer was given in the question itself. I was prepared to give that as an answer until I scrolled down to here. :)