# A word embracing different types of "measurement"

Tags: meaning

What would be a good word for different types of measurements?

Examples of the "measurements" I am thinking about:

Temperature, blood pressure, and blood sugar are body "measurements".

Airplane "speed, FPM" are plane measurements.

Comment: Why doesn't 'measurement' work? Are you looking for a single word that includes 'vital signs' or lab values' (those first ones) and the airplane metrics? Did you look in a thesaurus for 'measurement'? Any of those you wonder about?

Comment: Airplane "speed, FPM" are not plane measurements, they are performance data. A plane's measurements might be wingspan, weight, etc.

Comment: Related: [Is there a universal measure word in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453805/is-there-a-universal-measure-word-in-english)

Answer (score 2):

I have frequently heard the term ***"metrics"*** used as the word for the data comprising the quantitative results compared against a common measure.  Measure and meter both have similar roots: the Greek origin for 'measure' contains the the root for meter ('metron').

Typically, medicine and sports medicine fields will refer to the readings in your example as ***"biometrics."***

> The definition of ***bio-metrics*** is a branch of biology that uses measurement and statistical analysis to understand humans or animals.

[-Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/biometrics)

***"Performance metrics***" is another example for a term generally used by businesses to describe all of the data that might be used in a annual review.

> Standards of measurement by which efficiency, performance, progress, or quality of a plan, process, or product can be assessed.

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/metrics.html

As Weather Vane noted, the the measurements of a plane would be its dimensions, whereas its performance data would be its average speed at a certain altitude.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would benefit greatly from some sources to support your answer.

Comment: @Cascabel What do you mean? Like links to dictionary entries? Or something else? (if so, what?)

Comment: @Mitch I do not understand. Don't we usually ask for citations, sources and context for a good answer? BTW, I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @Cascabel is making a reasonable point. Instead of or in addition to "I have frequently heard" a dictionary definition and examples of use should be supplied. Then I'll up-vote it as it corresponds to my own experience of usage of the term.

Comment: @Cascabel:  https://xkcd.com/285/ Sure, it's reasonable to want them, but some answers we don't have the means to provide good sources.

Comment: @Cascabel No problem at all. Feel free to call.

Comment: I have edited to provide some supporting citations and sources. Feel free to roll back if you are not happy with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The word we use where I work is "[parametrics](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parametric?s=t)."  We have 26 different measurements in different areas that we use to analyze a given field office's performance monthly.  Some are percentages, some are number of days, some are means, etc.  That is to say that it is a variety of measurements in different areas encompassing different data and criteria.